# Intent filter action for receiving SIP call

Tags: android, android-studio, sip

I am making a SIP application based on SipDemo sample.
In Android developers website the say "When the SIP service receives a new call, it sends out an intent with the action string provided by the application. In SipDemo, this action string is android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL."

So, in my own app, should I put the same action name "android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL" or define a new one which I have no idea how to do it ?. I am really confused.

Any clue friends ??

Comment: you mean that android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL will work fine for my app even though it belongs to another application (SipDemo)  ?

Comment: You should read @ https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Comment: i already read that. i still don't get the point.